# Simplest way of running same SELECT on multiple data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have pretty simple select, let's say:

```
SELECT COUNT(added) FROM users WHERE added < "2015-07-30"
```

Can I run this select in some simple way not only for the given date, but also for, let's say, 7 days, each row showing count up to that specific day?

EDIT:
Here's my SQL building a table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 added DATE
);

INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-30");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-29");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-28");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-21");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-26");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-25");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-24");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-23");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-29");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-22");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2015-07-20");
INSERT INTO users (added) VALUES ("2014-02-10");
```

I expect result like that:

```
    DATE   | Count |
--------------------                   
2015-07-30 |  12   |
2015-07-29 |  11   |   
2015-07-28 |  10   |
2015-07-27 |   9   |
2015-07-26 |   9   |
2015-07-25 |   8   |
2015-07-24 |   7   |
```

Comment: You could create a `Stored Procedure` and have it accept a parameter for the date.  But I'm not sure what you mean by "simplest way."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(added >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AS last_14_days,
  SUM(added >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS last_7_days,
  SUM(added = CURRENT_DATE()) AS today
FROM users
WHERE
  added >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
```

you can also use it for counting all records before < "2015-07-30" and the last 7 days, but it will have bad performances, I would suggest you to use inline queries instead:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(added) FROM users WHERE added < "2015-07-30") AS before_30,
  (SELECT COUNT(added) FROM users WHERE added >= "2015-09-08") AS last_7
```

or an UNION query:

```
SELECT "Before 30" as Interval, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM users WHERE added < "2015-07-30"
UNION ALL
SELECT "Last 7" as Interval, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM users WHERE added >= "2015-09-08"
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, you need to use a GROUP BY query. If added is a date field (with no time information) you can use this query:

```
SELECT added, COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE added >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY added
```

**Edit**

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT d.added, COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT added
   FROM users
   WHERE added BETWEEN "2015-07-30" - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND "2015-07-30") AS d
  INNER JOIN users
  ON users.added <= d.added
GROUP BY
  d.added
ORDER BY `d`.`added` DESC
```

[**SQLFiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0d702/6)

Comment: Thank you for help, but I need 7 rows returned with value in each saying how much users were added in a system up to that day. I can do it with 7 SELECTS + UNION, but I would like to parametrise it later.

Comment: @downvoters I know this answer is not what he OP is asking for, but the OP keeps on changing the requirements ;)

Comment: I'm not changing the requirements, I'm adding more data to visualize what I need. If you look at my first description (before the edits) you'll see that query I showed returned count of the all entries added from the oldest one to given date. Grouping it by date gives me only information about how many users were added on each day. I didn't change the requirements one bit. Also my expected result from last edit is only an example, it can have different form if it's easier for you or for anyone.

Comment: @ZbigniewKisły it should be okay now

Comment: Wow, that works at last. It shows too many dates but that I can fix, thank you.